# How to put an image only in one method

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to paint an image in only the makeFrame() method, but when I compile, it says that paintComponent is not declared

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
i
```

Answer (score 2):

JFrame doesn't have a paintComponent method, but JPanel does! You might want to try putting your image on a JPanel then attaching the JPanel to your JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this it compiles no errors though I have to find where to put it to change the icon

```
public void paintComponent()
{
 ImageIcon imgIcon = null;
 image = POProject1.class.getResource("Software Engineer.jpg");
 imgIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
 Image img = imgIcon.getImage(); 
 this.setIconImage(img);
}
```